# If my iPad app is launched to open a file from another program, can I get currently running instances?

Tags: ipad, file, launch

My iPad app opens PDF files handed to it from other apps.  However, when another app calls it to open, my app launches and starts from scratch, causing the user to log in again and lose their place within the program.  Is there any way to open the already running instance and open the given file within it?

Comment: How are you handling the URLs now?

Comment: Well, right now it THEORETICALLY opens PDF files from other apps... I'm sifting my way through stuff to figure out how to implement this.  But so far, it restarts the program and I didn't want it to.  I will try implementing application:handleOpenUrl:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be implementing `application:handleOpenURL:`.